# Problem with graphics (Radeon)

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, drivers, cinnamon, amd-graphics

I'm having problems with my laptop that began some months after upgrading from Linux Mint 18 (Cinnamon) to 19.

My Sony Vaio has become almost unusable. Only to start it up, I need like 5-10 attempts. In most of the cases, the screen is greyed out I need to reboot it until it boots correctly.

Once I can log in, I can use it, but it's incredibly laggy. Cinnamon notified about problems with graphic drivers and the software rendering mode, but that's it. I've formatted it several times, trying with Linux 19, 18, Ubuntu 18 (with Ubuntu, there was no chance to log in at all), but the problem persists. Currently, I'm with Linux Mint 19 MATE because I feel that, when I can log in, it's less laggy than Cinnamon, but still painfully slow. I tried to install the drivers on my own from the AMD page but didn't work.

I leave the output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Host: julen-SVE1511V1EW Kernel: 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: MATE 1.22.0 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Sony product: SVE1511V1EW <filter> 
           Mobo: Sony model: VAIO serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde v: R0170E5 date: 03/23/2012 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 16.4 Wh condition: 16.4/45.0 Wh (36%) model: SONY Corp. VGP-BPS26 status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-2450M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Sandy Bridge rev: 7 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19956 
           Speed: 808 MHz min/max: 800/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] vendor: Sony driver: radeon 
           v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1366x768~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Sony driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-2: AMD Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500/6600 / 6700M Series] vendor: Sony driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-54-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Foxconn Unex DHXA-225 driver: ath9k v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: wlp7s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Sony driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 09:00.0 
           IF: enp9s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 810.43 GiB used: 10.33 GiB (1.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 840 EVO 120GB size: 111.79 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Hitachi model: HTS547575A9E384 size: 698.64 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 109.53 GiB used: 10.33 GiB (9.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 70.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: radeon temp: 64 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 219 Uptime: 16m Memory: 5.79 GiB used: 3.22 GiB (55.6%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.4.0 
           Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.32
```

Is there any hope for my laptop? It's been quite frustrating not being able to make it work. Ideally, I'd like to fix it for Mint Cinnamon, but I'm open to switching to any distro or base.